# NSArray from NSSet of objects crashes when calling 'allObjects'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an core data NSSet of objects through a relationship that I am trying to put into an array.

When I call the 'allObjects' selector I get a crash on my object in the NSSet that the selector does not exist.  Well, it obviously doesn't, but how do I get my data to copy into the array?

Heres the code that crashes.

```
NSArray *items = [surveyCategory.surveyQuestions allObjects];
```

Inside my surveyQuestions NSSet are SurveyQuestion objects.  And this throws the error `` `[SurveyQuestion allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ``

Any ideas on how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: What output do you get from this logging command? `NSLog(@"%@", [surveyCategory.surveyQuestions class]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message it looks as if `surveyQuestions` is not a to-many relationship
as you expect, but a to-one relationship, so that `surveyCategory.surveyQuestions` 
is a `SurveyQuestion` object and not a set.

Perhaps you changed the Core Data model and did not re-create the managed object subclass
file, so that the compiler did not complain.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, and I JUST noticed it about 2 seconds after I posted this question.  Go figure.

Comment: In an effort to help the readers, this answer should be accepted.